# Pulling data from Morningstar results in "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using the Morningstar Direct Excel Add-in to get fund holding data to Excel. The app inserts a formula to the currently selected cell, which then pulls fund holding data from Morningstar Direct. The inserted formula looks like this:

```
=@MSHOLDING("US52469L6609";"ISIN";"CORR=C, ASCENDING=TRUE, HT=ALL, 
WEIGHT=TRUE, FREQ=A, NAME=TRUE, SHOWHT=TRUE, SHOWCOUNTRY=FALSE")
```

So that I could pull data for multiple funds, without having to do it all manually, I have created the following VBA code to perform multiple pulls. For demonstration, the list contains only 2 fund ISIN codes.

```
Public Sub Get_Fund_Holdings()

Dim item

For Each item In Array("US52469L6609", "US64128K8760")

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = item
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Ticker"
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Formula = "=@MSHOLDING(""" & item & 
    """;""ISIN"";""CORR=C, ASCENDING=TRUE, HT=ALL, WEIGHT=TRUE, FREQ=A, 
    NAME=TRUE, SHOWHT=TRUE, SHOWCOUNTRY=FALSE"")"

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = item
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & _
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) 
  
Next item
    
End Sub
```

However, when I try to execute this code, I get the following error:

> "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

Is it even possible to run Add-in formulas using VBA?
Should I be using Application.Run to execute these kinds of formulas?

---

I even tried to use the Application.Run, but all it gives me is "-N/A"

```
Sub App_test()

ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = Application.Run("MSHOLDING", "US52469L6609", "ISIN", _
"CORR=C, ASCENDING=TRUE, HT=ALL, WEIGHT=TRUE, FREQ=A, NAME=TRUE, SHOWHT=TRUE, SHOWCOUNTRY=FALSE")

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Untested, but try changing the `;` to `,`.

Comment: `.Formula` requires US-EN format including separators (hence Ben's comment).  Alternatively use `FormulaLocal` and your local format